# Mercurial clone should prefer heads without bookmarks

Tags: git, mercurial, branch

I am attempting to reproduce the Git branching workflow in Mercurial.

Everything works well, except that when a user clones the repository he ends up on a feature bookmark because it is the latest commit on the "default" branch.

How do I get "hg clone" to update to the latest non-bookmarked changeset on the "default" branch?

Comment: If you want to reproduce the Git workflow, then every head needs a bookmark; there is no such thing as an anonymous branch in Git (well, other than detached HEAD state, but others can't see that), which is what a head without a bookmark is. You can name the primary head `master` if you want to mirror Git's usual naming policy, or you can use `@` instead; the bookmark `@` is special in that Mercurial will checkout the revision corresponding to that bookmark upon `hg clone` if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/Hg-update-should-prefer-heads-without-bookmarks-td4023171.html#a4023313:

> [you] should probably investigate using the **@** bookmark if you're using any bookmarks. It plays the same role for bookmarks as default does for branches.

This worked for me. Simply bookmark the latest non-bookmarked changeset with `@` and subsequent clone operations will work as expected.